# How to reverse each word in a string conserving spaces? [python]

Tags: python, string

I get how to reverse each word in the string. I've figured out two different ways to get that. The issue that I am running into is how to keep the same amount of spaces. For example in 'Hello  World' I only get one space in the output however I need two spaces.

```
def backward_string_by_word(text: str) -> str:
    list2 = []
    res = [i for j in text.split() for i in (j, ' ')][:-1]
    for word in res:
        list2.append(word[::-1])
    return ''.join(list2)
    
    
def backward_string_by_word2(text: str) -> str:    
    # TODO: figure out how to conserve spaces
    return ' '.join(x[::-1] for x in text.split())


print(backward_string_by_word("Hello  World")) # Should be two spaces but only holds one right now :(
print(backward_string_by_word2("Hello  World"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split on each space?

```
def backward_string_by_word(text: str) -> str:
    return ' '.join(x[::-1] for x in text.split(' '))
```

Or with regex:

```
def backward_string_by_word(text: str) -> str:
    return re.sub('\S+', lambda m: m.group()[::-1], text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey Mitch you are really close, try adding a ; after the first and second line. or add a space in the split command

Comment: What is the ; supposed to achieve, and how does your space suggestion differ from what I had already posted?